# sum of BITS is given find thar number

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

Problem Statement : You will be given a number N, and you have to tell whether there exist a number K so that sum of BITS in all the numbers from 1 to K is equal to N. If exist print that number, else print "Does Not Exist." without quotes.

Problem link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/BIT2/

My code complexity is `O((log n)^2)` and getting TLE People suggested me that It can be done in `O(log n)` but I am unable to figure it out.
 can some one help me how to do this in `log n`.

Below is My code with some pre-computation + `log(n)^2` This is what I have done.

[Solution](http://ideone.com/9CWYOD)

Comment: When you say O(log n^2) do you mean O((log n)^2) or O(log (n^2))? Because O(log (n^2)) = O(2 log n) = O(log n).

Comment: @ SchighSchagh Sorry its O((log n)^2)
@StephenTG c++;

Comment: @Luckymaster Some explanations on your code could help. Does it use binary search? How does `Total_Bits` work? Also, why do you think its complexity is `log(n)^2`? (I am asking because I think it's `O(log(n)^3)`)

Comment: Depending on the compiler you may find (1LL<<m) to be much faster than pow(2,m)

Comment: Yes I am using Binary search, as Binary search run in O(log n) it will call the function Total_Bits O(log n) times the complexity of Total bits is log n and Binary search is in Log n hens the Total complexity is O((log n)^2), correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hints

You are almost there already, consider your TotalBits function:

```
LL Total_Bits(LL n)
{  
    if(n==0) return 0;
    LL m = Lmb(n);
    n = n - pow(2,m);
    return (n+1) + Total_Bits(n) + m*pow(2,(m-1));
}
```

What you need to do is to convert this function into one that works out the bits of n (from most significant to least significant) in a single call given the target number of bits.  This allows you to remove the logn factor from using bisection.

How can you work out the bits of n?  Well, suppose we are trying to work out if we need a 1 at position m or not.  You can see from your code that if n>=2**m, then the answer will be at least m*pow(2,(m-1)+1, and if n<2**m, then the answer will be less.

### Python code

```
def find_index(N):
    """Compute the index K such that sum of all bits in numbers 1..K is N"""
    prefix = 0 # Number of 1's in the answer
    answer = 0 # Lower bound on index K
    for m in xrange(63,-1,-1):
        a = 1 << m
        extra = a*prefix + (m*(1<<m)>>1) # Amount we would add to our count if bit m is set
        if N>extra:
            N -= extra
            prefix += 1
            answer += a
    N-=prefix
    return answer if N==0 else "Does Not Exist."
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter de Rivaz for this nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in O((log n)^2). The pre-computation that you do is not necesary and besides is expensive. To check how given a number K, gets the amounts of 1 in numbers from 1 to K, check this [Count total set bits in all numbers from 1 to n](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-total-set-bits-in-all-numbers-from-1-to-n) . Knowing that, the rest is a simple binary search. My solution:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long ui64;

ui64 ones(ui64 n){
    ui64 ans = 0;
    int x = 0;
    for(int i = __lg(n); i >= 0; --i)
        if(n & 1LLU << i)
            ans += ((1LLU << i) >> 1) * i + 1 + (1LLU << i) * x++;
    return ans;
}

int main(){
    int t;
    ui64 n, l, u, m;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%llu",&n);
        l = 0; u = n + 1;
        while(l != u){
            m = l + (u - l) / 2;
            if(ones(m) >= n) u = m;
            else l = m + 1;
        }
        if(ones(l) == n) printf("%llu\n",l);
        else printf("Does Not Exist.\n");
    }
}
```